# Audio Jack Schematic

Tags: audio, connector

We are using this audio jack in our design. I am having trouble understand the schematic of this audio jack. My understanding is that

1. Pin 5 and Pin 4 : Audio left and right
2. Pin 2 or Pin 3 : Ground or
   Mic
3. Pin 1: detect

Can anyone confirm my understanding? I think that the switch is normally open and pin 3 will short with pin 1 when the jack is inserted. [image: Audio Jack]

Comment: Unless you want us to say something about the drawing or the footprint, perhaps you could crop the other 4/5 of the image out so we can read the schematic symbol with ease.

Comment: @Samuel  Right click, select `View Image` from the context menu (I'm assuming that you're using Firefox).  You'll get a larger image.

Answer (score 2):

I always use this standard here, that its the same the Nokia and Apple use:

[image]

With this schematic, I think that maybe the pins 2 and 3 can be shorted when the jack is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the circuit symbol is

- 1 = ground
- 2,3,4 = tip contacts
- 5 = switch, closed to 4 when NO plug is inserted

What the tip contacts are used for is not determined by the component but by convention and/or the exact device you want to use.