# What do I solder to a 3.5 mm jack to make sound come out of it?

Tags: audio, schematics, synthesizer

[image: Image of circuit from top][image: Image of circuit from bottom]
[image: Image of jack]
[image: Image of schematic]

I am trying to make a simple Atari punk console.i am new to electrical engineering. I am trying to figure out what to solder to each pin of the jack to make the finished product work.

Comment: GND to the sleeve, output to the tip (and output to the ring if you use a stereo jack).

Comment: Ground to the ground or Sleeve terminal. "-4 db Line Output" to the tip and ring terminals. Since it is mono output, and that's a stereo jack.

Comment: I know it's dumb, but where is the output?

Comment: @Serlintech the bit in your schematic labelled "output" is the output.

Comment: Yes, put there's no component called output so I'm confused. Do you solder the 10k resistor to the tip and ring? What do you solder to the tip and ring?

Comment: Let me rephrase, which component is the output?

Comment: The output is the node or junction where the 10k and 4.7k  resistor meet. You solder a wire from there to the pin on the audio connector...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Audio Jack Schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96618/audio-jack-schematic)

Comment: @Serlintech Do you understand how schematics work?

Answer (score 2):

Plug in a stereo cable, then use a multimeter to probe the pins at both end.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The schematic of this circuit contains only one output. The output is labeled as "-4 dB Line Output." Some circuits will have multiple outputs.

There are three ideas in the label:
 -> -4 dB (the nominal level where the units are actually dBu not dB).
 -> Line (Line denotes a relatively stronger signal used to directly drive a headphones or a speaker).
 -> Output (the function).

This circuit has a mono output (2 wires) not a stereo output (3 wires). Before soldering the jack to the circuit board, obtain a cable with a 3.5 mm mono male connector at each end. Plug one end of the cable into the jack. Use an ohm meter to determine which pin on the jack corresponds to the "tip" on the cable. Then, use the meter to determine which pin on the jack corresponds to the "sleeve" on the cable. Connect the tip of the jack to the output and the sleeve of the jack to ground (pin 7 on the 556).

In the photograph I see seven pins on the jack [this is probably a stereo jack (stereo  can have ~seven or fewer pins, mono can have ~five or fewer pins) which is completely ok for mono or stereo]. The middle pin on the jack is probably the tip. The outer four pins are probably all sleeve (ground). The two remaining pins are probably ring (not needed for mono, only used for stereo).  If you use mono headphones or a mono speaker, the ring can stay unconnected. If you use stereo headphones, connect an extra wire between the tip and the ring.

Comment: I disagree on your pinout description. I suspect the jack is a switched stereo jack. There are 5 pins on the jack. One sleeve, one ring, one tip, and then switched tip/ring pass-through. I'd expect the outer pins are the switch pass-throughs.

Comment: Thanks @Shamtam . . . after magnifying the photo, I also see five pins :)